# modinfo on running module without the corresponding .ko file

Tags: linux, kernel-modules

I can use `modinfo` on a .ko file.

Is there any way to use `modinfo` on module that already running, that I can see with `lsmod`, but I don't have the .ko file for?

Answer (score 0):

You can run `modinfo modulename` where modulename is the name of the module of the `lsmod` output (without .ko suffix). But if the module was loaded, then the .ko file must be somewhere in your filesystem like `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/...`.